# how do I use or in the predicate with array lengths for Postgres

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql

I hope this sql is self explanatory

```
select documentno, (regexp_matches(text, '|([^|]*)|'))[0] cat, (regexp_matches(text, '#([^#]*)#'))[0]::date promdate from s_ar_open
union
select documentno, (regexp_matches(text, '|([^|]*)|'))[0] cat, (regexp_matches(text, '#([^#]*)#'))[0]::date promdate from h_ar_open
where (array_length(regexp_matches(text, '|([^|]*)|'),1) > 0) or (array_length(regexp_matches(text, '#([^#]*)#'),1) > 0)
```

The code thingy is really a challenge.  Anyway, I get argument of or must not return a set, but doesn't array_length flatten the regexp_matches result?  I'm just looking for lines where regexp returns result in either of those two columns

Comment: For me this is not self explanatory. Please **[edit]** your question and add some [sample data](http://plaintexttools.github.io/plain-text-table/) and the expected output based on that data. [Formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). ([edit] your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments)

Answer (score 0):

When you have ONE match, you have a row:

```
t=# with c(s,p) as (values('blah','[a-z]'))
select regexp_matches(s,p),array_length(regexp_matches(s,p),1)
from c;
 regexp_matches | array_length
----------------+--------------
 {b}            |            1
(1 row)
```

but here no rows returned:

```
t=# with c(s,p) as (values('blah','[z]'))
select regexp_matches(s,p),array_length(regexp_matches(s,p),1)
from c;
 regexp_matches | array_length
----------------+--------------
(0 rows)
```

and here four:

```
t=# with c(s,p) as (values('blah','[a-z]'))
    select regexp_matches(s,p,'g'),array_length(regexp_matches(s,p,'g'),1)
    from c;
 regexp_matches | array_length
----------------+--------------
 {b}            |            1
 {l}            |            1
 {a}            |            1
 {h}            |            1
(4 rows)
```

so for the first sample using `array_length` on set looks usable as one row returned, but in two other cases - not. This way `array_length` does not flatten rows - only array elements. So you can't use it (because planner does not know ahead how many rows you have in `regexp_matches`) in `WHERE` with SRF to avoid:

> ERROR:  argument of WHERE must not return a set

[Read](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/4897.1358378623%40sss.pgh.pa.us) and similar

Comment: So what do I do in the where clause to differentiate result 2 from all the other results.  I saw this: You might want to stick it into a sub-select as per the trick suggested in the manual - then you get a NULL rather than zero rows when there's no match.  Maybe I should do where text ~* '|.*|' as the predicate.